# Searching for particular word in files

Tags: c#, regex, file

We have a requirement to replace word 'ABC'(dummied) with 'XYZ'(dummied) in all the files. We have hundreds of aspx/ascx/cs/xml/xsl files which might contain the word.

The requirement is

1. Do not replace word if it is part of NameSpace(eg ABC.A1.A2 should not be replaced) or variable names(var abc = "") or tags (abc:control).
2. The word should be replaced only if it is a whole word( In my cs file, if I have a variable name same as the word i am looking for, it should not be replaced . If I have a string literal eg var str = " ABC is good product". It should be replaced in this case

This will be 1 time activity. How do I parse entire file for the given word and replace it if condition is satisfied? Planning to use Regex.

Any other ideas is really appreciated. Does a tool already exists that does this? I have tried to google but could not find such a tool.

Comment: What is your definition of word? Do you need to consider punctuation? Could a "word" contain punctuation? For example: `students'`

Comment: What's left? How do distinguish 'hole word' and 'variable name' ?

Comment: word in my case is a particular word say 'abc'. I am looking for hardcoded values and string literals. so punctuation does not matter me.

Comment: @Yogendra: But punctuation does matter to the regex engine, so you need to answer Mark Byers' question. And Henk Holterman's, too.

Comment: @Tim, Yes, "doesn't matter" is usually the how a problem begins.

Comment: @Mark, @Henk ... the word may contain punctuation eg ABC's is the future. It doesn't matter. The new text should be XYZ's is the future.

Comment: I'd argue that "Planning to use regex" is how many problems begin....

Comment: So, will you be searching for the `ABC` in `ABC's` and replacing it with `XYZ`, or will you explicitly replace `ABC's` with `XYZ's`?  If the word you want to replace is `won`, you probably don't want to replace the first three letters of `won't`, but how can you avoid it?  Regexes don't know from words; to them it's all just a jumble of characters.  That's how *you* need to think if you want to find the right questions to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools like [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/) are always helpful. Together with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) you have a powerful toolset which helps to learn regular expressions and master every regex challenge.

Answer (score 2):

If this is truly a one-time activity, I'd vote for simply using Visual Studio Search/Replace, even if it's a bunch of solutions.  Why reinvent the wheel, especially since, realistically, you are much more likely to not do it correctly the first time, and have to undo hundreds of changes manually?

If you use source control (you do use source control, right?), I would **highly** recommend doing a diff on the files before you check them in, no matter what solution you use.

Comment: good point Wonko. I cannot use the VS search replace feature because the aspx files are not part of solution. But may be a doable thing

Comment: You can still open the aspx files in VS (just drop 'em on the open IDE), and search/replace in All Open Documents.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate if you can translate you requirements into regular expressions. Probably one filetype at a time.
Then, don' write a program but use an existing tool (SED).

But some of your rules seem very complex.